# HttpServletRequestWrapper not working in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logging, servlets, interceptor

I am developing a custom log with Spring MVC to get information from all incoming request. I would like to grab both the request body and response body. The issue is, even if I create a HttpServletRequestWrapper, I cannot forward the request after I process and wrap the request.

Here is my code:

**Interceptor**

```
@Component
public class LoggerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{

    final static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoggerInterceptor.class.getName());

    /**
     * Executed before actual handler is executed
     **/
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        MyRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new MyRequestWrapper(request);
        
        
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
        String date = f.format(new Date());
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        
        
        String method = requestWrapper.getMethod();
        String uri = requestWrapper.getRequestURI();
        String step = "Default Step";
        String url = String.valueOf(requestWrapper.getRequestURL());
        
        
        String serverName = requestWrapper.getServerName();
        String reqBody = IOUtils.toString(requestWrapper.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8").toString());
        
        CustomHttpResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new CustomHttpResponseWrapper(response);
        
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        String status = String.valueOf(responseWrapper.getStatus());

        String resBody = new String(responseWrapper.getBaos().toByteArray());
        
        if(step!=null && !step.isEmpty()) {
            log.info("INFO " + date + " " + uuid + "\n" +
                    "ID : " + getCurrentlyDateTime()  + "\n" +
                    "STEP : " + step + "\n" +
                    "Request URL: " + url + "\n" +
                    "Host : " + serverName + "\n" +
                    "Request Body : " + reqBody + "\n" +
                    "Response Status : " + status + "\n" +
                    "Response Body : " + resBody + "\n" +
                    "Response Time : " + end);
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Request Wrapper**

```
public class MyRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
     private final String body;
     
     public MyRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
           super(request);
           StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
           try {
                 InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
                 if (inputStream != null) {
                   bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                   char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
                   int bytesRead = -1;
                   while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                     stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                   }
                 } else {
                   stringBuilder.append("");
                 }
           } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw ex;
           } finally {
                 if (bufferedReader != null) {
                       try {
                           bufferedReader.close();
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                           throw ex;
                       }
                 }
           }
           body = stringBuilder.toString();
     }
    
     
     @Override
     public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
           final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
           ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
                 public int read() throws IOException {
                     return byteArrayInputStream.read();
                 }

                @Override
                public boolean isFinished() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isReady() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
           };
           return servletInputStream;
     }
    
     @Override
     public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
         return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
     }
    
     public String getBody() {
         return this.body;
     }
}
```

**Output**

```
INFO 2022/04/12 10:35:18:578 d00ec778-2a6e-4a72-a0e0-9649c13776eb
ID : 20220412103518
STEP : Default Step
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/com.ihcs.api.mobile/loginNew
Host : localhost
Request Body : {
    "username":"P0****",
    "sessionid":"*************************",
    "password":"********",
    "companyCode":"***",
    "UniqueId":"**********",
    "Manufacturer":"google",
    "Brand":"google",
    "Model":"*******",
    "DeviceId":"*******",
    "FcmTokens":"*******",
    "UniqueLogin":false
}
Response Status : 200
Response Body : 
Response Time : 18
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

I've tried some suggestions from stack overflow but still can't help. Thank you.

Comment: Evidently `IOUtils.toString()` closes the input stream, which isn't too surprising. You can't expect consuming the request input stream before executing the request to work anyway. Reconsider.

Comment: @user207421 Thank you for your advice. But when i use the getBody method from request wrapper the result is still the same.